# How to strings.Split on newline?

Tags: go

I'm trying to do the rather simple task of splitting a string by newlines.

This does not work:

```
temp := strings.Split(result,`\n`)
```

I also tried ' instead of ` but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: This should work with "\n". What was the result of you trying strings.Split(result, "\n")?

Comment: Yeah, I'd obviously messed that test up. Feel stupid now. :)

Comment: I would vote to close now because "this problem is the result of a typo and cannot be reproduced", but I think that others might have the same issue. How about we leave this as a sign-post?

Comment: It's not really a typo, it's a valid question, and people can easily mistake the use of backticks like that.

Comment: And the question helped me just now ;-)

Comment: I think possibly the confusion around usage of back-ticks has to do with the way you'd use `Split` on a regexp

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You have to use `"\n"`.

Splitting on `` `\n` ``, searches for an actual `\` followed by `n` in the text, not the newline byte.

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/KXjd4x2xwd)

Answer (score 45):

For those of us that at times use Windows platform, it can
help remember to use replace before split:

```
strings.Split(strings.ReplaceAll(windows, "\r\n", "\n"), "\n")
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JzOYUB7fz1Y)

Comment: Why not just `strings.Split(windows, "\r\n")` ?

Comment: @ymonad Good question, but if you use my approach the code will work correctly on both Windows and Linux to split files, if you needn't worry about cross-platform, then there would be no benefit.

Comment: @Cameron Why not using `ReplaceAll` instead of `Replace`?

Comment: @rodrigocfd Another good question! ReplaceAll was released as part of Go 1.12 on Feb 25, 2019, but I answered  Jan 13, 2019. So it wasn't available when I answered. I will fix it. :)

Answer (score 20):

It does not work because you're using backticks:

> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes ``. Within the quotes, any character is legal except back quote. The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes; **in particular, backslashes have no special meaning and the string may contain newlines**.

Reference: http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

So, when you're doing

```
strings.Split(result,`\n`)
```

you're actually splitting using the two consecutive characters "\" and "n", and not the character of line return "\n". To do what you want, simply use `"\n"` instead of backticks.

Answer (score 13):

Your code doesn't work because you're using backticks instead of double quotes. However, you should be using a `bufio.Scanner` if you want to support Windows.

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "strings"
)
 
func SplitLines(s string) []string {
    var lines []string
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(s))
    for sc.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, sc.Text())
    }
    return lines
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `strings.FieldsFunc` (this approach skips blank lines)

```
strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(c rune) bool { return c == '\n' || c == '\r' })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import regexp

var lines []string = regexp.MustCompile("\r?\n").Split(inputString, -1)
```

[`MustCompile()`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#MustCompile) creates a regular expression that allows to split by both `\r\n` and `\n`

[`Split()`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.Split) performs the split, seconds argument sets maximum number of parts, `-1` for unlimited

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>'</kbd> doesn't work because it is not a string type, but instead a rune.

```golang
temp := strings.Split(result,'\n')
```

go compiler: `cannot use '\u000a' (type rune) as type string in argument to strings.Split`

definition: `Split(s, sep string) []string`

Comment: I imagine that you didn't want to write `'\n'` but rather `"\n"` (or maybe you even wanted backticks?). Anyway, your answer is not really obvious, is it? Try to rephrase it better so that it makes sense for someone new with Go. Also — in which way does your answer differ from the accepted answer (which is far better explained)?